# Showing map is not function in react page after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I built a simple react app that fetch the users from database like **mysql**
After fetching data I want to pass data to child component and it works sometimes but when refresh page it throw error like data.map is not function
[here error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2tkb.png)
**my code of parent component**

```
import React,{useEffect, useState ,Context, createContext} from 'react'
import Sidenav from '../components/Sidenav'
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Content from '../components/ContentParent'
import RightSideNav from '../components/RightSideNav'
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Async from 'react-async';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import { get } from 'js-cookie';
const bodyData = createContext()
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    HomeDataContainer_parent:{
        backgroundColor:'#F2F2F2',
        display:'flex',
    },
    backdrop: {
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
        color: '#fff',
      },
}))
 function HomeDataContainer() {
    const [data,setData] = useState('')
    const [isload,setload] = useState(true)   
    useEffect(() =>{
       async function get(){
            fetch('/postsDrawer').then(async data => await data.json()).then(result =>{ setData(result)
             setload(false)
             
            })
        }
       get()
    },[data])
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
            
        <div className = {classes.HomeDataContainer_parent}>
        <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={isload} >
        <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
      </Backdrop>
            {/* sidenav */}
            <Sidenav/>
            {/* content */}
           
            if(data){
                <Content value = {data} />
            }
         
            {/* Right side updates */}
            <RightSideNav />
        </div>
    )
}
export default HomeDataContainer
export { bodyData }
```

**child component**

```
import React from 'react'
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import ArrowDropDownTwoToneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropDownTwoTone';
import ArrowDropUpTwoToneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropUpTwoTone';
import LocalOfferTwoToneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocalOfferTwoTone';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import QuestionAnswerIcon from '@material-ui/icons/QuestionAnswer';
import VisibilityIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';
import Logo from '../images/action.png'
import { BodyData }  from '../components/HomeDataContainer'

export default function HomeRecentQuestion(props) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const data = props.value
     let count = 0
    return (
        
        data.map(content => {
            let count = content.tags.split(',')
            return (
                <h1>{content.id}</h1>
        
            )
          
        })
        
    )
}
```

**how to resolve this**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2tkb.png):

Comment: what is this ? `<Content value = {mainData} />` you should use state for storing data and pass to children.

Comment: yeah i tried to use mainData after giving error but still giving error please give any other solution

Comment: initilize the use state with empty array `const [data,setData] = useState([])`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir your answer works and keep support newbies

Answer (score 1):

Change your data state to this:

```
const [data,setData] = useState([])
```

Change `useEffect` to this:

```
useEffect(() =>{
   if(!data.length)
     fetch('/postsDrawer').then(res=> res.json())
        .then(result => { 
            setData(result)
            setload(false)
         })
},[data])
```

Change your component to this:

```
<HomeRecentQuestion value={data} />
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, as you're creating an endless loop of useEffect refreshing when data is changed and changing data itself so in turn calling the useEffect callback again

Comment: did you see `if(!data.length)` ? also you can remove `data` from useEffect dependency, and remove this if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below on the child component.

```
data && data.map(content => {
            let count = content.tags.split(',')
            return (
                <h1>{content.id}</h1>
        
            )
          
        })
```

Comment: How can i render html from wysiwyg editors inside map

Comment: There are several ways, it can be done. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quilljs

Answer (score 0):

you will change it state of types when you created
like these: const [data, setData] = useState([]);
just you can it than problem will close it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).